# How to run tmux cmds in nodejs

Tags: shell, ubuntu, tmux, node.js

Is there any way to run tmux cmds like **tmux kill-server**, **tmuxinator attach** etc. through nodejs. I have searched online but not able to find anything useful which can aid me to remove my error.

I was trying this through **shelljs** npm module but it didn't work.

I am getting this error :-

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

when used these lines of code to run tmux cmds with nodejs :-

```
shell.exec('ssh -t myremotemachineaddress tmux kill-server');
shell.exec('ssh -t myremotemachineaddress tmuxinator start rails_servers');
```

Here, shell is a variable used for **shelljs** npm module.

Comment: Are you able to run other, simpler commands over `ssh`, such as `ssh -t machine echo Success`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it looks like you didn't set up publickey authentification on the remote host. Without that, you won't be able to log in without a password.
You have to generate a key pair on your machine and add the public key in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file in the user's directory.

To generate a key pair, use `ssh_keygen` (pressing enter twice when asked for a password will create a key without a password).

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 8192 -f ~/.ssh/id_yourmachine
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_yourmachine
```

`~/.ssh/id_yourmachine.pub` will be the public key, you should add to the file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the remote host.
Then you can login with `ssh user@yourmachine`.

Secondly, I'm not sure why you are using the `-t` option, but it's probably not needed and seems to be causing the first warning.

Apart from that, `node` has a built in way of [executing commands/starting processes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643470/execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js)